# How do you flip the coordinates in ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, survminer

I am trying to flip x and y for my survival analysis plot (using the survival/survminer package), but when I add coord_flip() to this line of code:

`ggsurvplot(poop_fit, data = egg.data, pval = TRUE, conf.int =  TRUE, coord_flip())`

I get this error:

`Error in .apply_surv_func(df, fun = fun) : Invalid 'fun' argument`

Does anyone know if there is another way to flip the coordinates in survival analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access/manipulate the plot by accessing it using '$plot', e.g. `ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)$plot`. For example:

```
require("survival")
require("survminer")

fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

ggplot1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)$plot
df1 <- data.frame(time=fit$time, nRisk=fit$n.risk, nRiskRel=fit$n.risk/max(fit$n.risk))  
ggplot1 + geom_point(aes(x=time, y=nRiskRel), data = df1, alpha=0.5, size=3)
ggplot1 + coord_flip()
```

Pre-flipped (no `+ coord_flip()`):

[image: pre-flipped.png]

Post-flipped (with `+ coord_flip()`):

[image: post-flipped]