# ggsurvplot() + lines(x, y, 'l')

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have a KM curve and I want to add a further line(not time-to-event) with "lines()" but this error occurs. Any tips?

```
dput(K_M_curves)
dput(output2)
OS<- Surv(K_M_curves$Time_to_Death_60 ,K_M_curves$Death_60_days)
```

`osfit<- survfit(OS\~ Treatment, K_M_curves)`

```
c<-ggsurvplot(osfit, K_M_curves, pval = TRUE , risk.table = TRUE, tables.height = 0.2, tables.theme = theme_cleantable(), legend.title ="Treatment" ,  legend.labs = c("xx", "No/Other Treatment"), palette = c("blue4","darkred"), ggtheme = theme_bw(), xlab = "Days", ylab = " Overall survival", pval.size = 3, pval.coord= c(50,0.25), log.rank.weights = "n" , surv.median.line = "hv")

l<- c+ lines(x= output2$time , y= output2$mean_OS_P , type='l', plot.new())
plot(l)`
```

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

Comment: AFAIK `ggsurvplot` returns a list where the ggplot is stored as the first element named `plot`. Hence, use c$plot to manipulate the plot. Second, it's a ggplot so trying to "add" base R graphics will not work.

Comment: Thank you very much!. Do you know any method to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `ggplot2`, you could do something like `c$plot + geom_line(.....)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you flip the coordinates in ggsurvplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819626/how-do-you-flip-the-coordinates-in-ggsurvplot)

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not solve the problem and I am trying different solutions. I have predicted mean survival probability and I am looking for a function able to extrapolate time and event data from OS probability so I can build a K-M with ggsurvplot. Any tips?